# MYSQL query results cut short when Sort is DESC and limited

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Seeing some strange things; help is being solicited.

I have a query, like so: (using CodeIgniter, btw)

```
'SELECT * FROM registers WHERE client_id='.$clid .' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT '.$num
```

`$num` is passed in through the function call (and it==15), and is echoing properly. But running this returns only 10 rows. If I explicitly set `$num` to 15, same thing. If I set `$num` to 20, it returns 11 rows! WTF's in my dome!

Howeverstance, If I set the order to `ASC`, instead of `DESC`, the original query runs as expected.

The query returns the expected number of rows when run in CocoaMySQL with either sort.

Any idears?

Comment: What do your MySql query logs tell you? What SQL actually landed in the database?

Comment: Everything looks OK in the logs:
       
`SELECT * FROM registers WHERE client_id=000690 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 15`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning the proper number of results. I had a clause that was preventing the rows from printing under certain conditions, and they were being met. Checked num_rows() and it was correct, so found the offending code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('registers');
$this->db->order_by('id','DESC'); //client_id='.$clid 
$this->db->limit(4); //'.$num
$query_result = $this->db->get();
$hasil = $query_result->result();
return $hasil;
```

Comment: please, provide an explanation to your answer

Comment: query using CodeIgniter for get last rows inside db ,